# Getting rid of the Android Action bar.

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar

When I create an android app this is generated automatically:

[image]

How do I get rid of this? Its ugly

**EDIT**

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size); 
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

**Note that this has to be called before setContentView(XYZ_xml)**

There are other Window Features too, like no action bar and no title etc. 
See the javadoc for more help

you can also add this to work with xml like this :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar
```

Comment: If you find an answer helpful, be sure to accept it.Click on the Tick!

Comment: 1 thing. When I take away the title, it makes my screen size larger doesnt it? But my screen size variables arent recognizing the difference

Comment: Screen Size variables meaning ?Please be more precise, and I would suggest you to ask a new question. I'll answer there.

Comment: At the start of my script I get the screenHeight and screenWidth through the function i just uploaded to my code

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the `<application>` tag your manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, use before setContentView():

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

try applying the theme to your activity in your manifest. You might have to change the theme depending on your support library:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Theme to you manifest like others have said. Avoid putting code in your java activity file instead because if you do that, when you run your application you will see the action bar for a very short duration (enough to notice it) before it goes away.